# How to enforce exactly one definition?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Given a **C** project that needs to support multiple environments, how do I use the preprocessor to enforce that exactly one environment is defined?

I can already do:

```
    #if defined PROJA
    (blah blah blah)
    #elif defined PROJB
    (etc)
    #else
    #error "No project defined"
    #endif
```

All that does, though, is tell me if 0 projects are defined.  If some helpful soul defines both project A and project B, the preprocessor will assume only project A.  However, the correct behavior, from my perspective, is to flag an error.

Granted, with only 2 projects defined this problem is trivial.  How do I solve it with 200?

Comment: with 200 a preprocessor hack would be utter pain to maintain, then you would rather need to make the makesystem take care of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe have different files

```
include_proja.h
include_projc.h
```

and then use your Makefile or whatever to include the right file. You can then generate 200 distinct files with the code and include the right ones at compile-time.

This kind of thing **is what build systems are for**. If you are doing something weird like this with macros ... find a better way outside the source code.

Each file can do (Excuse the verbosity here)

```
#define A_PROJECT_INCLUDE_WAS_INCLUDED
```

And then do

```
#ifndef A_PROJECT_INCLUDE_WAS_INCLUDED
    #error "No project include"
#endif
```

But some missing symbols will break it anyway in all likelihood.

**Good Luck**

Comment: "This kind of thing is what build systems are for. If you are doing something weird like this with macros ... find a better way outside the source code."

You are totally right.

Answer (score 3):

something like this:

```
#if defined PROJA
  #ifdef HAVE_PROJ
    #error 
  #endif

  #define HAVE_PROJ
#endif

#if defined PROJB
  #ifdef HAVE_PROJ
    #error 
  #endif

  #define HAVE_PROJ
#endif

#ifndef HAVE_PROJ
  #error No project selected (you need to define PROJA, PROJB, or ...)
#endif
```

Comment: I think this will get grim quickly and isn't really something that should be done in macros imho.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
#define ENV_UNKNOWN 0
#define ENV_MACOSX  1
#define ENV_LINUX   2
#define ENV_WIN32   3
/* and so on */


#ifndef ENVIRONMENT
/* no environment given, default to something (perhaps) */
#define ENVIRONMENT ENV_UNKNOWN
#endif

/* and now the environment specific parts */
#if (ENVIRONMENT == ENV_MACOSX)
#include "macosx_port.h"
#endif

#if (ENVIRONMENT == ENV_LINUX)
#include "linux_port.h"
#endif

#if (ENVIRONMENT == ENV_WIN32)
#include "win32_port.h"
#endif

#if (ENVIRONMENT == ENV_UNKNOWN)
#error You have to specify the ENVIRONMENT.
#endif
```

Now you can specify the environment you want to compile for on the command line, like this:

```
cc -DENVIRONMENT=2 ...
```

Another way is to include/link different modules from your build system depending on the environment you're compiling for.

Answer (score 2):

```
#if defined PROJA
bool one_project_defined = true;
#endif

#if defined PROJB
bool one_project_defined = true;
#endif

#if defined PROJC
bool one_project_defined = true;
#endif

#if defined PROJD
bool one_project_defined = true;
#endif

one_project_defined; // Won't compile in wrong builds
```

Comment: This is short and simple.  It does strike me as kind of hacky, though.

Comment: Until some helpful co-op doing maintenance work comes along and thinks, "Hey, this variable isn't being used any more..."

Answer (score 0):

The problem with nested ifs is that you'll end up with n^2 different tests for n projects.

You just need some expression that will give a compile-time error in this case. Perhaps:

```
#ifdef PROJA
#define PROJA-TEST "
#else
#define PROJA-TEST ""
#endif
```

and so on for B, C, etc.

Then:

```
const char *test_only_one_project = PROJA-TEST PROJB-TEST PROJC-TEST " "More than one project is defined!";
```

EDIT: ... of course this only tests that an odd number of projects are defined. But this should work:

```
#ifdef PROJA
#define PROJA-TEST (
#endif
```

and so on, then

```
const char *test_only_one_project = PROJA-TEST PROJB-TEST PROJC-TEST "More than one project is defined!" );
```

Comment: My first thought was, "Yeah, that's how I'd do it too."  My second was, "So is this why no one likes C anymore?"

Comment: Exactly. The preprocessor is pretty damn evil.

Answer (score -1):

perhaps you can do something like:

```
#if PROJ==A
(blah blah blah)
#elif PROJ==B
(etc)
#else
#error "No project defined"
#endif
```